How to create Dictionary with generic list
I try to make simple event bus that can contains Dictionary with lists of events by type.
But I cannot find a type of this dictionary that would not give out errors. Please help me figure it out.
Attaching my code with an example event subscription
EventBus class
private Dictionary<Type, List<Subscription<IEventCallback>>> _subscribers = new();


public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IEventCallback
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(action);

    Type type = typeof(T);

    if (!_subscribers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        _subscribers.Add(type, new List<Subscription<IEventCallback>>());
    }

    _subscribers[type].Add(new Subscription<T>(action)); // here I get an error "cannot convert from Subscription<T> to Subscription<IEventCallback>"
}

public void Publish<T>(IEventCallback action) where T : IEventCallback
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(action);

    Type type = typeof(T);
    List<Subscription<IEventCallback>> handler = new();

    if (_subscribers.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        handler = _subscribers[type];
    }

    foreach (Subscription<IEventCallback> subscriber in handler)
    {
        subscriber.Publish(action);
    }
}

EDIT
I solved the problem by making the event collection List < Object >. I don't really like this solution, but it allows me to understand the subject area further.
Attaching my solution below:
public interface IEventCallback {}

public class EventBus
{
    private Dictionary<Type, List<Object>> _subscribers = new();

    public static EventBus Bus => INSTANCE.Value;

    private static readonly Lazy<EventBus> INSTANCE =
        new(() => new EventBus());

    public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IEventCallback
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(action);

        Type type = typeof(T);

        if (!_subscribers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            _subscribers.Add(type, new List<Object>());
        }

        _subscribers[type].Add(action);
    }

    public void Unsubscribe<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IEventCallback
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(action);

        Type type = typeof(T);

        if (_subscribers.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            _subscribers[type].Remove(type);
        }
    }

    public void Publish<T>(T action) where T : IEventCallback
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(action);

        Type type = typeof(T);

        if (_subscribers.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            foreach (object subscriber in _subscribers[type])
            {
                Action<T>? callback = (Action<T>)subscriber;
                callback?.Invoke(action);
            }
        }
    }
}


Problem is like so many times (you are not alone): covariance. Even if the concrete T is-a IEventCallback , Subscription<IEventCallback> and Subscription<SomeClassThatIMplementsIEventCallback> are completely unrelated types.

^^ Which brings us to the question: why do you need a Subscription<T>? Why isn't it enough that all Subscriptions are Subscriptions of IEventCallback?

@Fildor It was planned that the structures will implement IEventCallback. Inside the Subscription class is System.Action <T>. If I leave IEventCallback only, I won't be able to access fields of that structures
I would like to get something like:
`Bus.Subscribe(OnKeyPressed); // subscription
Bus.Publish(new KeyPressEvent(@event.key.keysym.sym)); // invoke event `

"I won't be able to access fields of that structures" - you won't be so easily. It's not impossible, though. I believe if we know a little more about your code, we could come up with some solution for this.

You see, while the instances get referenced as the interface type, they still have all their full type information "under the hood". So, they would "know" what to do that's specific to their concrete type. This is the base for the "visitor pattern" family of methodologies. You could have the interface define a method that basically says "do your thing according to your actual type" if we wanted to put it very colloquially. And you can pass things to that method. Like a service or a callback ...

@Fildor
Thabk you!
Solved the problem by making the event collection List. I don't really like this solution, but it allows me to understand the subject area further.
